# G++ error: ‘<anonymous>’ has incomplete type

Tags: gcc, g++, typedef, void

I am forced to use a third party dongle access library that provides an include file 'sense4.h' with code as follows:

```
#if !defined _WINDOWS_

#define WINAPI
#define CONST const

typedef unsigned char   UCHAR;
typedef unsigned short  USHORT;
typedef unsigned int    UINT;
typedef unsigned long   ULONG;

typedef char            CHAR;
typedef char            TCHAR;

typedef void            VOID;

...

#endif /* !defined _WINDOWS */

...

unsigned long WINAPI S4Startup(
        VOID
);


unsigned long WINAPI S4Cleanup(
        VOID
);

...
```

The problem is that g++ 4.6.1 complains about lines of code where typedefed VOID is used:

```
sense4.h:375:9: error: ‘<anonymous>’ has incomplete type
sense4.h:376:1: error: invalid use of ‘VOID {aka void}’
sense4.h:383:9: error: ‘<anonymous>’ has incomplete type
sense4.h:384:1: error: invalid use of ‘VOID {aka void}’
```

Is there anything I can do without changing the 'sense.h' include file to make my project compile with g++?

#### Update 1

I found out that the section 18 of [C++ Standard Core Language Closed Issues, Revision 30](http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html) states:

> If the parameter-declaration-clause is empty, the function takes no arguments. The parameter list (void) is equivalent to the empty parameter list.
>
> Can a typedef to void be used instead of the type void in the parameter list?
>
> Rationale: The IS is already clear that this is not allowed.

Comment: @another.anon.coward, do I need to change title to "G++ error: ..."?

Comment: I guess you can & please do see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33101... might be related to this

Comment: `clang++` gives a more meaningful error : `error: empty parameter list defined with a typedef of 'void' not allowed in C++`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick summary: The code is not valid C++, though there's some lack of clarity about whether it should be.  Using `void` rather than `VOID`, or just using empty parentheses, will avoid the error.

<s>I think this is a bug in g++.</s>

I thought this was a bug in g++.  I'm now convinced that it isn't, though I argue that it would be better to make this a warning rather than a fatal error.

Normally in C++, a function with no parameters is declared with empty parentheses:

```
int foo();
```

As a concession to C compatibility, C++ also allows a C-style prototype, using `void` to indicate that the function has no parameters (since empty parentheses mean something else in C):

```
int bar(void);
```

g++'s interpretation seems to be that the `void` in this syntax here doesn't refer to the incomplete *type* `void`; rather, it treats it as a special syntax with a distinct use of the keyword.

I think you'll need to modify the header file to get g++ to accept it.

gcc accepts it as valid C, but that's not helpful if you need to `#include` it from a C++ source file -- unless you write a C wrapper and invoke it from your C++ code, which might be an acceptable workaround.

(Incidentally, I *hate* typedefs like that.  What's the purpose of `typedef void VOID;`?  Did the author think `void` was too confusing?  I suspect it's for compatibility with very old C compilers that didn't support the `void` keyword, but the need for that is long past.)

Here's the relevant description from the latest draft of the ISO C++ 2011 standard (8.3.5 [dcl.fct]):

> The *parameter-declaration-clause* determines the arguments that can
>   be specified, and their processing, when the function is called. [ ...
>   ] If the *parameter-declaration-clause* is empty, the function takes
>   no arguments. The parameter list `(void)` is equivalent to the empty
>   parameter list. Except for this special case, `void` shall not be a
>   parameter type (though types derived from `void`, such as `void*`,
>   can).

This implies that the `void` keyword in `int bar(void);` does refer to the type `void`.  <s>Since a typedef name is a synonym for the named type, `int bar(VOID);` should be equally legal.</s>  It would make the most sense for a typedef name like `VOID` to be accepted in place of `void`, but the wording of the standard actually refers to the keyword `void`, not to the type.

The whole purpose of permitting `(void)` is C compatibility.  Just to add to the confusion, the 1990 ISO C standard requires the `void` keyword; the 1999 and 2011 C standards changed the wording, allowing a typedef instead.  The response to [C++ Defect Report #577](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#577) confirms that the current wording requires the `void` keyword, and proposes a change that will permit a typedef -- but that change is not yet in any ISO C++ standard.  It will probably appear in the first Technical Corrigendum for C++ 2011, whenever it's published.

Thanks to [another.anon.coward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925381/another-anon-coward) for finding the existing [gcc bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33101).  I've added an overly verbose comment suggesting that the code is valid and the error message should not be produced -- and a later comment conceding that the code is invalid, but that a warning would be more appropriate than a fatal error.

In the meantime, I suggest contacting the provider of this `sense4.h` header file.  If they intended it to `#include`d only from C code, there's no real problem with it (other than the IMHO poor style); otherwise, they might consider using `#ifdef __cplusplus`, declaring the functions with `(void)` in C and with `()` in C++.  And you could go ahead and make that change yourself.  Whether g++ *should* accept the code or not, with a few changes it would be valid C, valid C++, acceptable to both gcc and g++, and better style.

If you've read this far and you're still awake, I'm impressed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think they had to make use of `#define` precompiler directive for that purpose instead of typedef.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33101.. but the remarks say not a valid code

Comment: Also `clang++` seems to give a more meaningful error `error: empty parameter list defined with a typedef of 'void' not allowed in C++`. So I'm guessing it may not be a bug in `g++`

Comment: @another.anon.coward: See my updated answer.  The message could be improved, but the code is not valid C++ (but it probably will be in a future standard).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Keith! You have left no stone unturned on this issue! I have contacted the provider of dongle library and reported the issue to them. Also, I have applied a temporary solution by substituting `typedef void VOID;` for `#define VOID void`.

Comment: Gods...  Just ran into this.  Thank you for your post and info!