# declaring a void parameter list with a typedef is nonstandard

Tags: c

I have a code snippet (legacy code) which has code similar to the following:

```
typedef void SPECIAL_VOID;
int func (SPECIAL_VOID)
{
    .....
}
```

GCC throws the following warning for this piece of code:
 Warning:  #494-D: declaring a void parameter list with a typedef is nonstandard

Why is GCC complaining and why is this non-standard ?

Answer (score 5):

This changed between C89 and C99.

C89 has (6.5.4.3):

> A parameter type list specifies the types of, and may declare
>   identifiers for, the parameters of the function.  [...] The
>   special case of `void` as the only item in the list specifies that the
>   function has no parameters.

In C99 this is changed to (6.7.5.3p10; 6.7.6.3p10 in C11):

> The special case of an unnamed parameter of type `void` as the only item in the list specifies that the function has no parameters.

This is occasionally taken to mean that in C89, only the literal token `void` (after preprocessing) is acceptable when declaring a 0-parameter function, while in C99 a typedef is allowed.  However, this is not the intent of the standard according to [defect report 157](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_157.html):

> Subclause 6.7.1 makes clear that it is a single parameter having the type `void` (as opposed to use of the `void` keyword) that indicates that a function takes no parameters. 
>   For clarity, Subclause 6.5.4.3 should be rephrased to emphasize that it is the type `void`, not the keyword `void` that matters.

For C++, [defect 577](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#577) brings C++ into conformance with C99; the resolution is not present in C++11 but is present in post-standard draft n3376 so can be assumed to be present in the next version of the standard, and likely in the first TC to C++11.  The typedef to `void` cannot be dependent on a template parameter for obvious reasons.  The question [G++ error: ‘<anonymous>’ has incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742135/g-error-anonymous-has-incomplete-type) discusses this issue with g++ and indicates that g++ will likely continue to reject the code for the time being.